# unistall google play service android

Tags: android, apk, adb

good morning

i would like to delete the google play services package from my android emulator because i tried to update it by a new version.

When i taped this command in my terminal:
./adb install com.google.android.gms.apk 
I receive this message :"install failed already exist "
I tried to unistall this package by this command:
./adb -e uninstall com.google.android.gms

It show me "failure".
My version is 3.1.36 and i would like to install 4 version to run my android map app
regards.....

Comment: You will not be able to uninstall play services as its only can be uninstalled by the administrator level. You can not uninstall it.

Comment: think you how can be an adminstrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK You will not be able to uninstall play services as its only can be uninstalled by the administrator level. You can not uninstall it on your own as it requires root level access..

Comment: how i can obtain root level access

Comment: AFAIK You can not get access of root level. If its possible then please tell me.

Comment: @GrIsHu There are plenty of utilities for rooting Android.

Answer (score 1):

Try **`adb install -r com.google.android.gms.apk`**

Comment: think you not worked for me i revive this message :INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES

Comment: Ah, okay. There is a certificate mismatch between the one installed and the one you are trying to install.

Comment: If you don't have a device and want to test on the emulator only, why don't you use an AVD with 4.2.2 or higher.

Comment: i tested in 4.2.2 n my api is 17 the version of the google play services lib in my project is 4132530

Comment: usually the same problem and in logcat i received this message google play services out of date requires 4132530 and found 3136130